# C99 ,variable placement in C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, variables, c99

I write C code with visual studio 2008.I want to place varibles "inside" the code.Like this

```
 int   main()
{
    foo();
    int i;
    foo(i)
    return 0;
}
```

Can I do it ?
For now this generates compile errors,despite that I compile it with /Tp option

Comment: Well, your code has at least two other errors, even in C99!  Plus, `/Tp` specifies that the file is C++.

Comment: What c99 did not introduce function overloading!

Comment: Assuming that you're using Visual Studio, `/Tp` is used to specify to the compiler that the input file is a C++ source file. C99 is not supported by Visual Studio.

Comment: I compile it with /Tp because I thought it will give me an option to define varibles inside the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile as C++. Or, perhaps, use this ugly trick with an extra block:

```
int main()
{
    foo();
    {
        int i;
        fum(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO, this trick isn't "ugly".  I use it all the time when I want to limit the scope of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio does not support C99, so to do what you want you either have to compile it as C++ or use a different compiler (such as the [MinGW](http://bellard.org/tcc/) toolset).